# Logging messages while entering and leaving a definition in python using a decorator for all definitions

Tags: python-3.x

I am not able to print `print("Leaving definition : " + func._name_)` in following code snippet

```
from functools import wraps
def notification(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def with_logging(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Entering definition : " + func.__name__)
        print("Arguments passed : {0} {1}".format(args,kwargs))
        d = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Leaving definition : " + func._name_) return d
        return d
    return with_logging

@notification
def addition_func(x):
   """"""
   return x


result = addition_func(4)
print(result)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) ?

Comment: What is the `return d` at the end of the line `print("Leaving...` ?